# Force update location LocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, locationmanager

I need to change the frequency of updateLocation on Location Manager to know if a user is closed to another location. In order to do this I've done the following code:

```
if(distance < 100.0){
        _timerForceUpdateLoc = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(forceLocationUpdate)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
}
```

calling the following method:

```
- (void)forceLocationUpdate
{
    if (self.locationStarted == TRUE ) {
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationStarted = FALSE;
    }else{
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationStarted = TRUE;
        NSLog(@"Longitude: %f — Latitude %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if i'm doing this right or not. Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you use `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`
method? The location updates every time user changes his position.

Comment: I tried it but it seems like this method is trigger every seconds or 1/2 seconds which is too slow for me. I'll make a test this weekend with a car to know if it works or not. Thanks for your answer